# CSS Margin with Quotation Marks

Tags: css, margin, semantic-ui

I was inspecting the source files of `semantic-ui` and noticed a rule in `semantic.css` like:

```
margin: '';
```

At the beginning, I thought it was a typo but this rule is used in 3 different lines. I searched Google for it but couldn't find anything. Is it just an error or is it something working? Does anyone know why to use such a rule?

Comment: Invalid rule. Here's examples of how `margin` is used correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: Yes, and it would default to `initial`...

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes to what? Is it valid? I tried it with an IDE and shows it as an error.

Comment: Yes, it's invalid. I can't speak for your IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Summary

My guess is that this is a mechanism to allow using a LESS variable, which is supposed to be overwritten by a theme but can also be null. Without declaring the variable the LESS would not compile to CSS. And with setting the value of the variable to something valid like `initial` you cause an unwanted behaviour. So they *drop* the property by making it invalid if the theme does not set it.

#### Example

I'll show what I mean by taking the example of the [horizontal divider](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/divider.html#horizontal-divider).
The compiled CSS is:

```
.ui.horizontal.divider {
  display: table;
  margin: '';
  /* ... */
}
.ui.divider {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  /* ... */
}
```

In the GitHub repository you'll find the [LESS for the horizontal divider](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/src/definitions/elements/divider.less):

```
.ui.horizontal.divider {
  display: table;
  margin: @horizontalMargin;
  /* ... */
}
```

The variable declaration can be found in the corresponding [.variables file of the theme](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/src/themes/default/elements/divider.variables). In the default theme it is just `@horizontalMargin: '';`.
This will result in giving the horizontal divider the margin of the more general `.ui.divider` which is shown above (`margin: 1rem 0;`) and which is different from valid values for margin like `auto`, `initial`, `inherit`, `unset`.